# reading 2 files at time (line by line) in scala

Tags: scala, for-loop

I'm new to scala and I hit this problem:

```
def main(args: Array[String]){

val source = Source.fromFile(args(0))
val target = Source.fromFile(args(1))

for (lines <- source.getLines ; linet <- target.getLines) { 
  println(lines + " =source| target= " + linet);
}
}
```

If source and target file contain plain numbers: 1, 2 (one number on each line), the results is:

```
    1 =source| target= 1 
    1 =source| target= 2
```

However, I'd expect:

```
    1 =source| target= 1 
    2 =source| target= 2
```

Problem: the second file (target) is read correctly (line by line, i.e. 1 and 2), in the first one (source), only the first line (i.e. 1) is read.

Most likely problem lies in for-loop. I though operator ";" behaves like "&&" so one line should be read from both files at time. I tried replaced ";" by "&&" but it didn't work.

any clue will be deeply appreciated! Tomas

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can [zip](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala#L684) them and iterate through line pairs:

```
def main(args: Array[String]){

  val source = Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines
  val target = Source.fromFile(args(1)).getLines

  for ((s,t) <- source.zip(target)) { 
    println(s + " =source| target= " + t);
  }
}
```

The problem with your approach is that the code written like for(x <- xs, y <- ys) produces cartesian product. In your case it stops to yield items of product as far as first iterator is traversed (bear in mind -- iterators traversable only once).

**UPDATE.**

Your for loop is analog for this in java/C++/...:

```
for(int i = 0; i < source.length; i++)
  for(int j = 0; j < target.length; j++) {
    String s = source[i];
    String t = target[j];
    // println ....
  }
```

(Besides that fact, that above I haven't used iterators)

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but isn't the second file traversed more than once in his example, not the first one?

Comment: @Kane nope, if he turned iterators to the lists (you may check this by yourself) he'll got "1s -> 1t", "1s -> 2t", "2s -> 1t", "2s -> 2t" where 's' stands for source and 't' for target, but because both iterators exhausted, you only get "1s -> 1t", "1s -> 2t". It's even easier to check if you place 1 and 2 into source, and 3 and 4 to target.

Comment: @xhudik so you unhappy with zip?

Comment: om-nom-nom - cool, a I didn't know zip([link](http://abel-perez.com/scala-zip-function)) function -thanks. It will be working well with smaller files (whole content put into variable) - I'll try to come up with solution for line by line processing (big files)

Comment: @xhudik as long as you work with iterators there will be no significant difference  if file is big or not

Comment: @om-nom-nom- sorry, I was wrong. I thought getLines gives all lines but it gives just an iterator i.e. your solution is working also for big files, where it is not possible to read whole content into a variable. Once more - THANK YOU!